# How Do I mock a DAO Layer using JMockit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, jmockit

I am trying to mock a DAO layer Interface which looks something like this ...

```
      public interface DummyDAO{

     public List<VO> getSearchCriteria(String Id, Integer version) throws Exception;

      }
```

In the implementation part, I run a query, and it fetches me a list of Value objects based on that query. How do I mock a List of VO's coming from a database. Is there a simple way to do this ?. I am trying to encourage my team to use Jmockit but I am still a newbie to this mocking tool. If you need more info please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here can depend partly on how the CUT (code under test) is using the `List<VO>`. For example, if your code is a RESTful service merely acting as a proxy and returning this `List<VO>` to the user, without examining the contents or anything, then this would suffice:

```
@Tested CUT cut;
@Injectable DummyDAO dao;
@Injectable List<VO> res;

@Test
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    new Expectations() {{
        dao.getSearchCriteria(anyString, anyInt); result = res; 
    }};
    List<VO> output = cut.methodBeingTested();
    // assertions go here, like that output and res are the same
    // you can also put Verifications here
}
```

If you are expecting to do analysis of the `VO`s then things can get more complex, like for example:

```
@Tested CUT cut;
@Injectable DummyDAO dao;
@Mocked VO vo;

@Test
public void testSomething() throws Exception {
    final List<VO> res = new ArrayList<VO>();
    Collections.addAll(res, vo, vo, vo, vo);
    new Expectations() {{
        dao.getSearchCriteria(anyString, anyInt); result = res;
    }};

    new Expectations(4) {{
        vo.getFoo(); returns(5, 47, 13, -7);
    }};

    cut.methodBeingTested();
    // assertions go here, like that you handled the negative number properly
    // you can also put Verifications here
}
```

Notice here I did not mock the `List` -- if you are doing more complex operations it's better to stick with a real `List` and not have to mock all of its operations. I mock a single VO and add it to the list multiple times--this is OK because each time you examine it it will act differently and thus seem to be a different `VO`.

The examination, because it is happening 4 times, I moved to a different `Expectations` block since you are expecting it to happen 4 times. I'm just doing this to show off the expectations block since in this case it could be just as easily accomplished by having `vo.getFoobar(); times=4; returns(5, 47, 13, -7);` in the original block... alternatively, this second block could look like

```
    new StrictExpectations(4) {{
        vo.getFoo(); returns(5, 47, 13, -7);
        vo.getBar(); returns("foo", "bar", "baz", "quux");
    }};
```

In this case, the `times` field would not work and you'd have to have it in a separate block - this block is saying it expects to have `getFoo()` and `getBar()` called, alternating, exactly 4 times--as you would want to do if iterating through a list and looking at both properties each time.

I hope I have given you food for thought; without knowing more of your specific use case I can't be more specific myself.

Comment: Thanks for the Heads up. That was helpful.

Comment: +1 But it should be `@Injectable DummyDAO dao` (not "@Mocked"), so that the mocked dao instance gets injected into the `@Tested CUT cut` object.

Comment: Mea culpa. You are (of course!) right. I’ll fix it. Thank you for the insight and the excellent tool!

Comment: Lets say I have a DAOImpl class which has a getMethod() inside it. If I have to call this method inside this class, Do I need to add Tested and Injectable annotations to the class ?

Comment: `@Tested` only applies to the class you are actually testing. Unless DAOImpl is what you are testing, steer clear. `@Injected` would be suitable here, though. Declare an `@Injectable DAOImpl` and record your expectations in whatever sort of StrictExpectations/NonStrictExpectations/Expectations block you have going.

Comment: Yes I have a DAO Impl class which has a search Criteria method which has Id and version as arguments. If I pass the Id and version, It has to return me a List of Vo's. I am trying to set  Vo values and then adding them to the list. Is there a way to get the VO List using this method when I pass id and version ?.

Comment: Comments aren't really suited for this sort of thing. You should consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do that is using Mockito.spy() .The spy method create a proxy of your instance that give to you the opportunity to simulate the behavior of one method.

You could create one list that will be returned when you call your dao method.

Example:

```
yourDao = spy(new YourDaoImplementation())
        doReturn(yourExampleList).when(yourDao).getSearchCriteria(any(String.class), any(Integer.class));
```

If you really want to test your dao, you could use a light weight data base as HSQLDB

Comment: Yes you are right, my solution is using Mockito instead of JMockit